# Find if classes child class has empty innerHTML in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, class

I am trying to figure it out whole day already and nothing seems to work, so I would really appreciate help. Here is simplified example of what I have in HTML:

```
<div id="big-div">
    <div class="middle-div">
        <div>Child:</div>
        <div class="small-div">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle-div">
        <div>Child:</div>
        <div class="small-div">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle-div">
        <div>Child:</div>
        <div class="small-div"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Result is:

```
Child:
1

Child:
2

Child:
```

What I would like to achieve is to show `middle-div` only if `small-div` has any content, so the result would be:

```
Child:
1

Child:
2
```

I have tried this approach:

```
const element = document.getElementById("big-div");
let middle = element.getElementsByClassName("middle-div");
let small = element.getElementsByClassName("small-div");

for (let m = 0; m < middle.length; m++) {
    for (let s = 0; s < small.length; s++) {
        if (small[s].innerHTML = "") {
            middle[m].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

and the result looks like this:

```
Child:
Child:
Child:
```

I have also tried this:

```
var small = [...document.getElementsByClassName("small-div")];
var disappear = function () {
    if (small.innerHTML == "") {
        parent.small.display = "none";
    }
}
small.forEach(disappear);
```

But that didn't do anything and `console.log(small.innerHTML);` showed `undefined`.

Can someone help me figure out how to do this correctly?

Comment: Your double loop combines every `middle` element with every `small` element. Surely, you want to combine only the n-th `middle` element with the n-th `small` element. Your other attempt should read `var disappear = function (small) {...}`,  the function called by `.forEach` needs an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd find all the `.small-div` elements inside `.middle-div` elements inside `#big-div` and if the don't have any child nodes, add a class to the `.middle-div` that hides it:

```
const smalls = document.querySelectorAll("#big-div .middle-div .small-div");
for (const small of smalls) {
    if (!small.firstChild) {
        small.closest(".middle-div").classList.add("hide");
    }
}
```

Live Example (hides the elements after 800ms):

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    const smalls = document.querySelectorAll("#big-div .middle-div .small-div");
    for (const small of smalls) {
        if (!small.firstChild) {
            small.closest(".middle-div").classList.add("hide");
        }
    }
}, 800);
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="big-div">
    <div class="middle-div">
        <div>Child:</div>
        <div class="small-div">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle-div">
        <div>Child:</div>
        <div class="small-div">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle-div">
        <div>Child:</div>
        <div class="small-div"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to allow for a single node that has whitespace and still consider that div "empty", you could use:

```
const smalls = document.querySelectorAll("#big-div .middle-div .small-div");
for (const small of smalls) {
    if (
        !small.firstChild ||
        (small.childNodes.length === 1 && !small.firstChild.nodeValue.trim())
    ) {
        small.closest(".middle-div").classList.add("hide");
    }
}
```

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    const smalls = document.querySelectorAll("#big-div .middle-div .small-div");
    for (const small of smalls) {
        if (
            !small.firstChild ||
            (small.childNodes.length === 1 && !small.firstChild.nodeValue.trim())
        ) {
            small.closest(".middle-div").classList.add("hide");
        }
    }
}, 800);
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="big-div">
    <div class="middle-div">
        <div>Child:</div>
        <div class="small-div">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle-div">
        <div>Child:</div>
        <div class="small-div">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle-div">
        <div>Child:</div>
        <!-- Note that now it has a text node with whitespace -->
        <div class="small-div">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, second version is the one I have adjusted and it worked! As a new person in programming I would have never guessed this approach. I very much appreciate code snippets as well :)

Answer (score 0):

to do that you need to select all the "middle-div" elements, and for each one it selects the "msall-div" element inside it.

Then check if the inner HTML of the "small-div" element is an empty tring, and if it is, set the "display" style of the "middle-div" element to "none".

this will hide the "middle-div" element if the "small-div" element is empty.

I hope I understood your question correctly.

Here is the code snippet, since you indicate that you have not been able to solve it:

```
const element = document.getElementById("big-div");
const middleDivs = element.getElementsByClassName("middle-div");

for (let i = 0; i < middleDivs.length; i++) {
  const smallDiv = middleDivs[i].getElementsByClassName("small-div")[0];
  if (smallDiv.innerHTML === "") {
    middleDivs[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it did work on example, but for some reason it didn't work on the real version. You could not have adjusted to something you didn't see though.

Answer (score 0):

when you are using double loop it is increasing the TC and make sure a condition that when m will be equal to s then this will work and you can make it also for two times only.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).